# More flexible memory management

Tags: java, memory

In the past I have made most of my memory and performance critical applications with C++ or C#, but with the latest improvements in the Java language I figured I might give it a try. However I am already stuck pretty early with the memory management in Java. More specifically the following two points are really surprising me:

- Why do I have to tell the JVM how much memory it can use? Couldn't it just use whatever it wants? I mean... take whatever you need?
- Why is it so greedy with memory? Cant it be a bit more generous in giving back memory to the OS? Check the following example:

The example I mentioned above:

- Started with 2048mb of heap space
- At time T0 the application uses 300mb of RAM
- I open and fully read to a byte array a 400mb file -> 700mb of RAM
- I wrap that array into a ByteBuffer -> 700mb of RAM
- I decrypt it into a second array (cant be done in place) -> 1100mb of RAM
- I close the file and clear the ByteBuffer and set the encrypted array to null -> 1100mb of RAM
- I parse the decrypted array (which produces a little bit less data) -> 1350mb of RAM
- I set the decrypted array to null -> 1350mb of RAM
- I wait for a while -> 1350mb of RAM
- If I repeat the above with 1028mb of heap space -> OutOfMemoryException

So my question is: Why is Java behaving that way? And more importantly, can I tell the JVM to be a bit more... sane? C# is also a managed language, but it manages to properly free unused memory.

Comment: Why do you think you have to tell the JVM how much memory it should use...? Did you just come here to rant?

Comment: I am not sure about your comment, @Tunaki . I specifically dont want to tell it how much memory it should use. I want it to use as much as it needs and as little as possible. It already is using as much as it can use, but sadly it is not doing the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I have to tell the JVM how much memory it can use?

You don't. It has a reasonable default maximum of 1/4 of main memory up to 32 GB.

> Couldn't it just use whatever it wants?

It could, you could set the maximum to be all your free memory.

> I mean... take whatever you need?

It does this, but up to some maximum you set so it doesn't impact other applications.

> Why is it so greedy with memory?

It depends on how you use it.

> Cant it be a bit more generous in giving back memory to the OS?

That depends on which GC you use.

> Started with 2048mb of heap space

I assume you mean 2 GB or 2048 MB (mb is a milli-bit and a pet hate of mine sorry)

This is a really small amount of memory these days, I assume this is just an example. c.f. my 9 year old has an old desktop of mine with 24 GB of memory.

> I open and fully read to a byte array a 400mb file -> 700mb of RAM

I would memory map the file. This uses almost no heap.  BTW You can memory map in C and C# too, this is not a trick specific to Java.

> I wrap that array into a ByteBuffer -> 700mb of RAM

A memory mapped file is already a ByteBuffer. at this point your heap is no bigger.

> I decrypt it into a second array (cant be done in place) -> 1100mb of RAM

I would do this to another "direct" buffer. again no more heap has been used.

> I parse the decrypted array (which produces a little bit less data) -> 1350mb of RAM

So this uses an extra 250 MB.

> I set the decrypted array to null -> 1350mb of RAM

This changes the reference to be `null` but nothing else. That is just one of your buffers above in any case.

> I wait for a while -> 1350mb of RAM

If you do nothing, you wouldn't expect anything to happen.

> If I repeat the above with 1028mb of heap space -> OutOfMemoryException

This is because you are retaining memory and you have less the second time around.

In short, I would

- use memory mapped files.
- use native buffers
- note you can clear these deterministically if you really need to, but usually you don't.
- don't touch the maximum heap unless you need to.

> And more importantly, can I tell the JVM to be a bit more... sane?

I suspect "sane" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Why is using 1/4 a reasonable amount? If I have 32gb of RAM the application should eventually use up to 32gb of RAM if it really needs 32gb of RAM and also eventually give it back to the OS, if it no longer needs it. I do like the idea that you can tell an application how much it can use at most, however it would be nice, if it were a bit more flexible and think of other applications too.That aside from your message I assume that the only immediate solution is to use native memory management again and handle all by myself like I would in a non-managed language?

Comment: What I also probably forgot to mention is, that I am solely talking about desktop applications, not server applications.

Comment: @Cromon Java is designed to run on machines with other applications, not one program should use all the resources of the machines unless you really want it to.

Comment: @Cromon you don't need to do any more handling yourself.

Comment: @Cromon Java tends to be designed for servers more than a desktop for just one user.

Comment: I am totally with you, that a program should be kind of "social" with other applications, @PeterLawray which is what surprises me even more. It kind of "hurts my feelings" that my program is using 1.5gb of RAM even though I know that almost 1gb could easily be given back to the OS for other applications. If I ran my application in C# it would also end up with 1.5gb after parsing, but after some time it slowly would go back to 500mb because the objects die. Thats what my original question was aiming at: Can I tell the JVM to consider memory only as a maximum and not kinda sorta minimum too

Comment: @Cromon Java does that esp with the G1 collector which will be the default in Java 9. If you use native regions this works much more immediately.